# processing copy/duplicate resize issue

Tags: java, processing

not posted before, so be patient.

I'm having an issue in the processing IDE with copying PImages and then resizing. Resizing a copy of an image also appears to resize the original.

```
void setup(){
  size(10,10,P2D);
  PImage img;
  img = loadImage("nickwire.jpg");
  println(img.width);

  PImage dupe;
  dupe=img;
  dupe.resize(10,10);
  print(img.width);print("\t");println(dupe.width);
}

//console outputs:
//263
//10  10

//I'm expecting
//263
//263  10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a copy of your image, you are creating a new reference and pointing it to the same image.

In order to copy the image to the new reference, take a look at the [`PImage#get()`](https://processing.org/reference/get_.html) method.

Comment: Have spent some time at this already, I can't see how to use the copy function to achieve what I'm trying to do - can you give an example?